# php function variables not getting passed

Tags: php, function, variables, ftp, http-post

I am trying to create a simple script that will upload a file to a server using ftp. My setup consists of 3 files. index.php which is the interface, config.php that holds some default configuration values and transfer.php that includes the various functions. Config and transfer are added to index.php using require_once.

Inside the index file I have a simple form that reads some values (ftp host, username, password etc) and at the same time displays them on that page. Then, when the user clicks a link, a php function is called using the code below:

```
if (isset($_GET['transfer1'])) {
      ftp_upload($server, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass, $dest, $destinationfile, $rem_path, $path, $unzipper, 'files');
      (!ftp_upload ? (list($result,$error) = array('File Transfer failed','1')) : $result = "File transfer completed successfully");
  }
```

And the function inside transfer.php looks like this:

```
function ftp_upload($ftpserver, $user, $pass, $dest, $destinationfile, $rem_path, $path, $unzipper, $stage) {
  $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
  $conn = @ftp_connect($ftpserver) or die ("Cannot connect to $ftpserver");
  $login = @ftp_login($conn, $user, $pass) or die ("Cannot login as $user - $pass<br />");
  if($stage == 'files') {
      $upload = ftp_put($conn, $dest, $destinationfile, FTP_BINARY);
      (!$upload ? false : true);
  } elseif($stage == 'unzip') {
      $upload = ftp_put($conn, $rem_path.$unzipper, $path.$unzipper, FTP_ASCII);
      (!$upload ? false : true);
  } elseif ($stage == 'sql') {
      $upload = ftp_put($conn, $rem_path.'/backup.sql', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/backup.sql', FTP_BINARY);
      (!$upload ? false : true);
  }
  ftp_close($conn);
}
```

As you can see, values regarding the transfer (user/pass etc) should get passed to the function. The problem is that although they appear (that's what the func_get_args() does) to be passed, they do not work. For example, if I use the form to change the ftp hostname, the main page displays it correctly, but the value that gets passed is the default from the config.php file.
In theory, this file allows values to be overridden by using something that looks like:

```
(isset($_POST['server-host']) && $_POST['server-host'] != '' ? $server = $_POST['server-host'] : $server = "test.com");
```

However, all the above simply do not work. As far as the main index.php file goes, all values are updated and should be passed to the function, but they don't.

Maybe someone can point out my mistakes or at least point me in the right direction???

Thanks!

P.S: To get a better idea of what I am trying to do: I have an index.php file that includes 2 files. One of them (config.php) has default values that can be overridden by $_POST data (see above isset() statement). The other one is transfer.php, that handles the ftp upload stuff. The function works perfectly if I hard-code required values, but when I use the first if statement to check $_GET, the variable passed to the function is not the updated one, but the default value...

Comment: ftp_upload($server, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass, $dest, $destinationfile, $rem_path, $path, $unzipper, 'files'); How are the arguements of this function set? Right now I dont see the GET/POST vars set at all.

Comment: Do you include your config.php somewhere?

Comment: That code is hideous. You are badly abusing the ternary operator. It's one thing to use it to decide how to assign one of two values to a variable, but doing OTHER assignments inside those values is just bad. As well, using the `@` operator is very bad form. it's the equivalent of stuffing fingers in your ears and going "lalalala can't hear you".

Comment: remove @ from ftp_connect and check the connection is working

Comment: @colburton All files are included in the main index.php file

Comment: @fortune my problem is not really the connection itself. If I hard-code the hostname inside the function, it works with or without the @...

Comment: @swiss_blade have u checked the function arguments received correctly inside the function?

Comment: @fortune that's where my problem is... although the correct value is shown on the main index (taken from the $_POST), the function gets the default value from the config file...

Comment: You should test at the end of your config file what the value of $server is. This way you can narrow it down. Also "(!ftp_upload ? (list($r ..." will not work, since ftp_upload is a function.